# Converse to Riesz-Thorin Theorem

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, banach-spaces, harmonic-analysis

Let $T$ be an operator on simple functions on (say) $\mathbb{R}$.

The Riesz-Thorin interpolation theorem, in one form, says that the Riesz type diagram of $T$ is a convex subset of $[0,1]\times[0,1]$.

My question is about the converse:
Is every convex subset of $[0,1]\times[0,1]$ the Riesz diagram of such an operator? Does the answer change if we are allowed to replace $\mathbb{R}$ with a general measure space $X$?

It is not clear to me how to find such a $T$ even for very simple regions, such as convex polygons or circles.

Comment: What do you mean by "Riesz type diagram" ?

Comment: The set of $(1/p,1/q)$ such that $T:L^p\to L^q$ is bounded.